# Check if path resolves to a subfolder of the PHP script

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

We have a site that uses a [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to change a request for a folder like `example.org/home/products/widgets/` into a request for `example.org/home/index.php?path=/products/widgets/`

That rule looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ ./index.php?path=$1 [NC,QSD,NS]
</IfModule>
```

The `index.php` then lists details of various files that are genuinely in that folder location.
(i.e. `/home/products/widgets/` exists and contains files, but I want requests for the folder to be redirected to the index.php)

This works, but my question is: how do I reliably detect/prevent someone from using this maliciously to access other folders that are not subfolders of `/home/`?

Right now someone could sneakily request `example.org/home/index.php?path=/products/../../secretstuff`

Do I need to do something in the PHP with [`realpath()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) or is this something I can control in the `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: You should handle this in PHP. Assuming your internal URL format was known/got exposed due some error elsewhere, I could simply request `/home/index.php?path=/any/path/i/like` directly in my browser, without even needing your current rewrite setup in place. You would have to write an additional set of RewriteCond(s)/RewriteRule, that validates the query string content, to prevent me from doing _that_.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe that was my suspicion. I just wasn't sure if mod_rewrite had some way to handle it I was missing. So I guess this is really a question about how best to handle it in PHP then.

Comment: Use `realpath` to get any `../` resolved, so that you have the full, absolute file system path. Then simply check if that value starts with the full, absolute file system path to the folder you want to restrict this to (including the trailing slash).

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, I found an answer similar to that so I'll close this one.

Comment: You might want to also consider `FallBackResource` instead, and avoid the QS completely with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. I _think_ all traversal attacks would be mitigated by that then.